# Поместить значения из datatable(jsf) в коллекцию

Tags: java, jsf

Имеется `datatable` на JSF странице с столбцами, которой являются название продукта, его цена и input поле количества этого товара. При нажатии кнопки нужно загрузить в коллекцию элементы из `datatable`, где значение введенного количества больше 0 (метод `addCups()`).

Как можно корректно это реализовать?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class OrderBean extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
@Autowired
private OrderDAO orderDAO;

@Autowired
private OrderPositionDAO orderPositionDAO;


private Map<Long, Integer> selectedItems = new HashMap<>();

private Integer quantityOfCups;

public Map<Long, Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    return selectedItems;
}

public void setSelectedItems(Map<Long, Integer> selectedItems) {
    this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
}

public Integer getQuantityOfCups() {
    return quantityOfCups;
}

public void setQuantityOfCups(Integer quantityOfCups) {
    this.quantityOfCups = quantityOfCups;
}


public void addCups(Long id, Integer numOfCups){
    if(numOfCups > 0){
        selectedItems.put(id, numOfCups);
    }
    if(numOfCups == 0){
        selectedItems.remove(id);
    }
    System.out.println(selectedItems);
}
```

JSF страница

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{coffeeBean.allCoffee}" var="coffee">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.coffeeName}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.costForCup}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{orderBean.quantityOfCups}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="add cups" action="#{orderBean.addCups(coffee.id, orderBean.quantityOfCups)}"/>
</h:form>


</html>
```

Comment: Вот вариант решения: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40795711/1341148 Суть его в том, что вводимые Пользователем значения передаются на сервер сразу (при потере фокуса полем ввода), а нажатие на кнопку лишь подтверждает действие но данные из таблицы не передаёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнём разбирать код по порядку:

1) `coffee` видна только в рамках компонента `p:dataTable`, так как объявлена в внутри него. Параметр `coffee.id` в выражении `#{orderBean.addCups(coffee.id, orderBean.quantityOfCups)}` примет значение `null`.

2) Выражение `#{orderBean.quantityOfCups}` ссылается на одну переменную и для каждой строчки будет перезаписываться.

Путей решения приведённой задачи может быть много, самые очевидные: добавить в `coffeeBean.allCoffee` поле количество чашек либо повесить слушатель на поле ввода. Для количества страница:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{coffeeBean.allCoffee}" var="coffee">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.coffeeName}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.costForCup}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{coffee.quantityOfCups}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="add cups" action="#{orderBean.addCups()}"/>
```

bean

```
public void addCups(){
    for(Coffee coffee: coffeeBean.getAllCoffee){
         if(coffee.getQuantityOfCups > 0)
             selectedItems.put(coffee.getId(), coffee.getQuantityOfCups);
         if(coffee.getQuantityOfCups == 0)
             selectedItems.remove(coffee.getId());
    }
}
```

Для слушателя:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{coffeeBean.allCoffee}" var="coffee">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.coffeeName}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{coffee.costForCup}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{orderBean.quantityOfCups}">
            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@this" listener="#{orderBean.addCups(coffee.id)}"/>
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

bean

```
public void addCups(Long id){
    if(quantityOfCups > 0)
         selectedItems.put(id, quantityOfCups);
    if(quantityOfCups == 0)
         selectedItems.remove(id);
}

public Integer getQuantityOfCups() {
    return quantityOfCups;
}

public void setQuantityOfCups(Integer quantityOfCups) {
    this.quantityOfCups = quantityOfCups;
}
```